State Management for Real-Time Data Updates in React with TypeScript
I’m building a React application with TypeScript that processes real-time data streams. Using useState and useEffect causes excessive re-renders, impacting performance. How can I optimize state management for frequent updates, perhaps using Context, Redux, or another library?
What I tried:
I started by exploring TypeScript's built-in utility types such as Partial, Omit, and Pick to create the desired nested type transformation. For example:
type NestedPartial<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object ? NestedPartial<T[K]> : T[K];
};

I also experimented with conditional types and recursive mappings to handle deeply nested objects. For instance, I tried something like:
type TransformDeep<T> = T extends object 
    ? { [K in keyof T]: TransformDeep<T[K]> } 
    : T;

This approach worked well for constructing deeply nested structures but failed when I attempted to dynamically combine transformations (e.g., Partial and Readonly) based on specific conditions.
To troubleshoot, I attempted to create separate utility types for each transformation and then compose them. butt, this resulted in type errors or unexpected behavior due to how TypeScript evaluates deeply nested structures.

What I expected:
I expected to define a type that applies one or more transformations (such as Partial or Readonly) to all properties in a deeply nested structure, dynamically determined by runtime or type-level conditions. My goal was for TypeScript to infer the desired transformed structure without throwing errors or losing type safety.
For example:
type Input = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: string;
            d: number;
        };
    };
    e: boolean;
};

type ExpectedOutput = {
    a?: {
        b?: {
            c?: string;
            d?: number;
        };
    };
    e?: boolean;
};

This is where I got stuck—how to dynamically combine transformations while ensuring TypeScript accurately infers deeply nested structures, all without requiring excessive boilerplate code.
